# Is it possible with nDepend and CQL today to ask for classes directly using classes of a derived type?

Tags: ndepend, cql, cqlinq

Been reading through a lot of Q's and posts and see that subqueries/nested queries/query composition will not be supported until the next version. However I'm not sure if that is what I need, in my head it I would write it that way but I might be complicating things.

I imagine it like

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN
SELECT TYPES WHERE
      IsDirectlyUsing "MTNE.Web.OneWeb.^.*\p{Proxy}+$" IN
      SELECT TYPES WHERE DeriveFrom "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol"
```

So what I'd like to do is check if types are directly using other types in a given namespace which has the suffix Proxy, and that the proxy type is derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol. If a type is directly using the proxy type announce a warning.

Suggestions, hints, tips, pointers or answers anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to write the query asked with [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Certainly the most elegant, concise and optimized way is:

```
warnif count > 0
let soapClientTypes = Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol"))
let mnteTypes = Application.Types.WithFullNameLike(@"MTNE.Web.OneWeb.^.*\p{Proxy}+$").ToHashSet()
from t in soapClientTypes.UsingAny(mnteTypes)
select new { t, 
             mnteTypesUsed = t.TypesUsed.Intersect(mnteTypes) }
```

Notice how [we first define 2 sets](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Perf.aspx#TimeComplexity), and also use the extension method [ToHashSet()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Helpers.ExtensionMethodsSet~ToHashSet.html) to optimize the execution of the [Intersect()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Helpers.ExtensionMethodsSet~Intersect.html) method.

Notice also the usage of the method [UsingAny()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsSequenceUsage~UsingAny.html) that, in a single call, perform a lot of work.

Comment: Sounds good for the future, but I would have needed it now. I see the true power CQL, but not having subquery or composing queries is hindering quite a bit. Looking forward!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I've been trying to write.  Sounds like the next version will be very powerful tool.